# using relational operator in array passed by subcript operator using classes in c++

Tags: c++

```
class cary
{
private:
    int arr[20];
    int count;
public:
    void get_input();
    int &operator [](int);
    int operator <(const cary& );
    int operator >(const cary& );
    cary()
    {
        arr[0]=0;
    }
};

#include<iostream.h>
#include "asign.h"

int &cary::operator [](int index)
{
    if(index<0||index>20)
    {
        cout<<"index out of bound \n";
    }
        return arr[index];
}
int cary::operator < (const cary& c2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
    count=arr[0];
    if(count< c2.arr[i])
        return count;
    }
}
int cary::operator > (const cary& c2)
{

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
    count=arr[0];
    if(count> c2.arr[i])
        return count;
    }
}

void main()
{
    cary a1,a2;
    int n;

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {

        a1[i]=i*10;
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        cout<<"element at"<<i+1<<"="<<a1[i]<<endl;
    }
    if( a2<a1 )
        cout<<"smalest value is"<<endl;
    if(a2>a1 )
        cout<<"greatest value is"<<endl;


}
```

there is a program for operator overloading of subscript and relational(< and >
) operators i want to write a program which enter an array of integer by subscript operator and determine the smallest and greatest value in array by using relational operator (< and >)..

Comment: there is a program for operator overloading of subscript and relational(< and > ) operators i want to write a program which enter an array of integer by subscript operator and determine the smallest and greatest value in array by using relational operator (< and >)..
plz help me..

Comment: @HafsahJaved: Try to state in simple clear sentences the outcome that you expect. The description and the code are different, and moreover, the description does not make sense, use `operator<` (which compares two `cary` objects to find the minimum value in one array goes against all design recommendations. If you provide `operator<` to compare to `cary` it should tell you which of the two `cary` is smaller, not what value inside the first of them is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, Instead of writing for loops, you can do,

```
int minimum = *std::min_element(arr, a+20);
int maximum = *std::max_element(arr, a+20);
```

I hope that should make things easier and more readable for you.